# What are some reasons an object will serialize to XML but will not Deserialize back into an object?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

Here is what i have.(just the user class, functions, and function calls. I just grabbed them out of the code for the reference) Serialization works just fine, its only the Deserialization that wont work... I run my program and enter the user information and it serializes to the XML just fine....I have it set up to immediately Deserialize to admin when the program starts up. But when I go to view the user all I see is "Unknown" for each entry.

```
public static User admin = new User();
admin = DeserializeFromXMLUser();

//Send user to user config XML file
static public void SerializeToXMLUser(User user)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(User));
    TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"G:\\Projects\User Config.xml");
    serializer.Serialize(textWriter, user);
    textWriter.Close();
}

//Grab user info from user config XML file
static User DeserializeFromXMLUser()
{
    XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(User));
    TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(@"G:\\Projects\User Config.xml");
    User user;
    user = (User)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
    textReader.Close();
    return user;
}

//Creating a User Object Class
public class User
{
    public string userEMail { get; set; }
    public string userPassword { get; set; }
    public string userCell { get; set; }
    public string userSMTP { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        userEMail = "Unknown";
        userPassword = "BpGusTrn3/59drIJCB6eRw==";
        userCell = "Unknown";
        userSMTP = "Unknown";
    }
}
```

and here is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<User xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <userEMail>someone@somewhere</userEMail>
  <userPassword>BpGusTrn3/59drIJCB6eRw==</userPassword>
  <userCell>1234567890</userCell>
  <userSMTP>some-smtp.server.com</userSMTP>
</User>
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me.  Something else is going on.  Are you sure your deserialize code is getting called?

Comment: It gets called the moment the application loads

Comment: AHH CRAP! you was right. a line of code two lines above the call was timing out lmao